# I am facing weird pinching .Is there anything wrong with this topology?

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

When I increase the geometry it reduces the pinching little bit but doesn't remove completely . Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Topology seems fine at first sight at least. You probably just need higher subdivision.

Comment: I can't say a lot from the images but I have some thoughts, please provide the .blend, click [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: Quad flow is not optimal but it isn't too bad. Looking at the design though are you sure subdivision suits you better than bevel?

Comment: @Mateus I have uploaded the blend file. Thanks for your valuable response

Comment: @kheetor sorry but I didn't understand what you said. I haven't used bevel modifier . Just 1 mirror modifier and 1 array modifier. Thanks

Comment: Yes I was asking if you have tried to achieve the rounded look with bevel modifier instead subsurface? I am suggesting you try it. It's the most optimal for simply rounding sharp corners which seems to be what you're doing.